# pass data from a TableView to the contained Views of a PageViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, segue, uipageviewcontroller

I have a tableview with a list of names and what I wish to have is when pressing one of the cells inside the tableview to pass the name content of the cell to an upcoming page view controller containing 2 different views.  I am using a library called pulley in which I am not able to do segues by pushing modally so inside of the 'didSelectRow' method I am doing this

```
let pagevc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageVC") as! PageViewController

(parent as? PulleyViewController)?.setDrawerContentViewController(controller: pagevc, animated: true)
```

to accomplish the segue to the pageviewcontroller. This should be right.
But the 2 Views inside the pageviewcontroller View, they all need the Name of the selected cell. So I did this:

```
pagevc.name = selBarName
```

and to be sure i did the same for the 2 views of the page controller like  this(*still inside of didSelectRow method of the previous tableview class*):

```
let detvc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailVC") as! DetailVC
    detvc.barname = selBarName
    
    let speisevc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SpeisekarteVC") as! SpeisekarteVC
    
    speisevc.barname = selBarName
```

but printing the var barname in each class shows that the var is still an empty string. Only the var name of pagevc has changed to the wanted Name.
So I instantiated the two views inside viewdidload of the PageViewController Class but it still doesn't pass the data from the pagevc to the other 2 views contained in the pagevc.

I hope I could make the problem clear. If you need more input tell me what is missing. Basically I just need to know how to pass a String from the PageViewController to its contained Views. By now i am able to pass the name of the selected cell to the pageviewcontroller but not to the views that are presented by the pageviewcontroller.

**Edit:**

The PageController itself should be correct because using just 2 empty views inside it which doesn't require the var name works all fine.

Here is part of the class PageViewController just to make things complete:

```
class PageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    
    var name = ""
    
    var pageControl = UIPageControl()
    
    
    
    lazy var orderedViewControllers: [UIViewController] = {
        return [self.newVc(viewController: "DetailVC"),
                self.newVc(viewController: "SpeisekarteVC")]
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print(name, "hierpageview") //THIS NAME IS PRINTED CORRECTLY AS WISHED
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self
        
        
        let speisevc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SpeisekarteVC") as! SpeisekarteVC
        
        speisevc.barname = name
       
        let detvc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailVC") as! DetailVC
        detvc.barname = name
        print(detvc.barname, "dhdhfhdah") //THIS ONE IS ALSO PRINTED RIGHT BUT PRINTING IT INSIDE THE ACTUAL CLASS RETURNS AGAIN AN EMPTY STRING !!!
        
        
        if let firstViewController = orderedViewControllers.first {
            setViewControllers([firstViewController],
                               direction: .forward,
                               animated: true,
                               completion: nil)
            
        }
     
     func newVc(viewController: String) -> UIViewController {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewController)
    }
    
    
  
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1
        
        
        guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
          
             return nil
        }
        
        guard orderedViewControllers.count > previousIndex else {
            return nil
        }
        
        return orderedViewControllers[previousIndex]
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1
        let orderedViewControllersCount = orderedViewControllers.count
       
        guard orderedViewControllersCount != nextIndex else {
          
             return nil
        }
        
        guard orderedViewControllersCount > nextIndex else {
            return nil
        }
        
        return orderedViewControllers[nextIndex]
    }
    
    
}   
      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by :

- Create a string in your destination root controller.
  (say for example `let barName : String = ""`)
- In your didSelectRow method, store the data into the string against your desired indexPath. (say for ex., `view.barName //name of your string = // value you want to store, for example if it is an array then maybe myArr[indexPath.row]`)
- Then in your destinationViewController, in viewDidLoad method, push value onto the desired label. (say for ex., `yourLbl.text = barName`)

Comment: Yes i already did this as i tried to explain but i can only push the value to my PageViewController like this. Somehow its not possible to push the same value also to the 2 views inside of the PageViewController.

Comment: do the same for the other views as well then @AlperMaraz

Comment: I did but it doesn't work. Maybe i shouldn't try to push the value inside of the viewdidload method of the PageViewController but i don't know where else to do it.

Comment: can you post code of your SpeisekarteVC and DetailVC ? @AlperMaraz

Comment: i don't think they are relevant. At least they just need to receive the change of the string value. Both have the var barname = " " and in all the other cases where i don't have a PageViewController inbetween changing the value of this var inside of the didSelectRow method of the TableView works fine.